# Integration over WHAT, when finding the expectation of an operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Let's consider a system of N 3D particles, the expectation value of an operator:

$\langle A \rangle=\sum_rP_rA_r=\sum_r\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta E_r}A_r$

First question here: Why are we assuming that the probabilities have the exact same expression as the probabilities for the system of being in an arbitrary microstate, when we associate the system with the canonical ensemble?

Then, we write for the expectation value of the operator $A$:

$$\langle A \rangle_k=\frac{1}{N!Z_{kl}}\int\int A_{kl}(\vec x_1..\vec x_N,\vec p_1,..\vec p_N)e^{-\beta H_{kl}}\frac{d^3p_1}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}...\frac{d^3p_N}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}d^3x_1...d^3x_N$$

The general expression for the expectation value of an operator is:

$$\langle A \rangle_k=\int A(?)\rho(?)d\vec ?$$

The $?$ is supposed to represent the variable over which we are integrating. I assume that this is different for different operators. Am I correct in this?

Now, let's transform the initial expression for the expectation value, for a single particle in a box:

$$\langle A \rangle_k=\frac{1}{Z_{kl}^{(1)}}\int\int A_{kl}(\vec x,\vec p)e^{-\beta H_{kl}}\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}d^3x$$

where $Z_{kl}^{(1)}=\frac{V}{\lambda^3}$ where $V$ is the volume and $\lambda$ is the de broglie wavelength.

If we consider the position operator $\vec X$ and momentum operator $\vec P$. If we want to find the expectation value of $\vec X$ we write:

$\langle \vec X \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \rho(x)dx$. Here we integrate ONLY over x, to find the expectation value.

For $\vec P$, we do the same thing, but we integrate ONLY over $p$.

Now if I would want to find, let's say $\langle \vec X \rangle$ and utilize the expression for finding the expectation value of an operator for a single particle, there we integrate over x and over p. Isn't this a problem? Will I get the same result for  $\langle \vec X \rangle$ , whether I use:

$$\langle \vec X \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \rho(x)dx$$

or

$$\langle A \rangle_k=\frac{1}{Z_{kl}^{(1)}}\int\int A_{kl}(\vec x,\vec p)e^{-\beta H_{kl}}\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}d^3x$$

Comment: IMHO your question is not very clear; you ask multiple, not very well-motivated questions and state somehow contradicting things... What are you asking? Have you checked any book on statistical mechanics and QM?? As it seems, you're mixing up many things.

Comment: I have, and the reason why I wrote this Thread is because the two questions I asked, confuse me. One was the fact that the probabilities, are the probabilities for the canonical ensemble, and the 2nd thing was the integration region. I even gave a concrete example. I considered the position operator, how we find it's expectation value, while integrating over x, and how we can also find it, by using the expression for a single particle in the box. I don't see where the unclarities, or the contradictions

Comment: "One was the fact that the probabilities, are the probabilities for the canonical ensemble" -it makes no sense. You say "we do this or that"- no, "we" don't. give a reference and context! You're, for some unknown reason, just stating more or less random things. Again: You should go back to any text book on QM or stat mech. and check the definition of expectation values. Your first question is like: "We assume $x=4$. Why do we assume this?" Answer: The question is ill-defined.

Comment: Canonical ensemble: $Z=\sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}$ and the probabibility of the system occupying an arbitrary microstate is :$P_n=\frac{1}{Z}E^{\beta E_n}$. This is from a textbook. And if you look, the expression  $P_n=\frac{1}{Z}E^{-\beta E_n}$ is exactly the same as the expression of the probability $P_r$ multiplying an arbitrary value $A_r$, that the operator $A$ takes in an instance

And here, from wikipedia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble#:~:text=An%20alternative%20but%20equivalent%20formulation%20for%20the%20same%20concept%20writes%20the%20probability%20as

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression that you are trying to extend classical stat mech to quantum. The formalism is different, although some formulas may appear similar.

In the classical case, your observable $A$ is defined on phase space, which can be parametrized by canonical variables $p,x$ (possibly multidimensional). Your ensemble is characterized by a positive density function $\rho$ on the phase space. Phase space is defined by a symplectic structure which gives a natural measure, which gives in canonical coordinates:
$$
\langle A\rangle =\int \rho A dpdx
$$
with the normalization:
$$
\int \rho dpdx =1
$$

In the quantum case, the notion of phase space is not well defined. It is simpler to reason on the Hilbert space an operators. This leads to the density matrix formalism. An ensemble is now defined by a positive hermitian operator $\rho$ which gives the expected value of a observable $A$ (now a hermitian operator on the Hilbert space):
$$
\langle A\rangle =\text{Tr } (\rho A)
$$
with the normalization:
$$
\text{Tr } \rho =1
$$
For a motivation of this formalism check out Hall’s *Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians*.

Note that in QM, $x,p$ are not simultaneously diagonalisable due to the uncertainty principle:
$$
[x,p]=i\hbar
$$
However, in the limit $\hbar\to0$ you recover the classical limit since they commute and you can express the trace as the classical integral, now interpreted as a trace on the simultaneous diagonal basis.

For the canonical ensemble, in the classical case:
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta H}\\
Z=\int e^{-\beta H}dpdx
$$
while in the quantum case:
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta H}\\
Z=\text{Tr }e^{-\beta H}
$$
Despite the similarity in the formulas, they represent different objects and predict different expected values. Take for example the harmonic oscillator: $H=\frac{p^2+x^2}{2}$ which disagree at low temperature (the agreement at high temperature is a general phenomenon).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question is a bit unclear, but my general answer to "what do you integrate over to find an expectation value?" is this:

In quantum mechanics, you pick a basis (generally either position or momentum) and you express your wavefunction and operator in that basis. Then find the expectation by integrating over either $x$ or $p$, whichever basis you chose. In the position basis:
$$<\hat{O}> = \int dx \psi^{\dagger}(x) \hat{O(x)} \psi(x).$$

In quantum stat mech, the process is very similar, but we often compute integrals over energy $E$ or momentum $k$. For example, we can compute expectation of an operator $\hat{O}(E)$ via:
$$<\hat{O}> = \int \hat{O}(E)n(E) D(E)dE$$
Where $n(E)$ is the average occupation number given by Bose or Fermi statistics and $D(E)$ is the density of states. $D(E)$ is a well defined and dimension-dependent function of energy that can be found in any stat mech textbook. This expression can be transformed into an integral over $k$ by a change of variables.

For the specific problem you mention of N particles in a box, you can solve via the quantum stat mech method I just mentioned if you know the statistics that your particles obey. Note that it doesn't make sense to write an operator as a function of both $x$ and $p$ as you do in your question. It's either one basis or the other.

Comment: Consider to use \langle and \rangle for $\langle$ and $\rangle$, respectively.